# show custom fields data in next and previous link in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to show a advanced custom fields data in previous post link in wordpress. But The data is not showing also it breaks the html as well.

```
<div class="prev-posts pull-left">
<?php
$prev_post = get_previous_post();


if($prev_post) {
   $prev_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $prev_post->post_title));
   echo "\t" . '<a rel="prev" href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_title. '" class=" ">
   <strong>

   <<< &quot;'. $prev_title . '&quot;

   </strong>
   <img src="'.the_field("girl_image").'" alt="'.the_title().'/>


   </a>' . "\n";
                }
?>
</div>
```

In this code the "girl_img" field contains the URL of an image. I want to show the image based on the URL. But it is showing the URL itself instead of showing the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_field()` instead of `the_field()`.

`get_field()` = Returns the value of the specified field.

`the_field()` = Displays the value of the specified field. This function is the same as `echo get_field($field_name)`;

Replace  `the_field("girl_image")` with `get_field("girl_image")`